# Storing value to variable

Tags: php, arrays

Hello guys i have seen a code which is really confusing to me.The code is

```
$array = array('Alpha' => 1.1,'Bravo' => 2.2,'Charlie' => 3.3,'Delta' => 4.4,'Echo' =>5.5, 'Golf' => 6.6);

$pos = 3;

function getAtPos($tmpArray,$pos) {
    $keys = array_keys($tmpArray);
    return array($keys[$pos-1] => $tmpArray[$keys[$pos-1]]);
}

$return = getAtPos($array,$pos);

var_dump($return);
```

Just see the 5th line of the code .It returns an array with `$keys[$pos-1]` as key and `$tmparray[$keys[$pos-1]` as value .

I just need to know wheather the value of $pos-1 stores to $keys ..and the value of `[$keys[$pos-1] stores to $tmparray ..`

Please help me to understand this ..Any help would be appreciated ..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand the question.. but

```
return array($keys[$pos-1] => $tmpArray[$key[$pos-1]]);
```

returns the array thats inside the $array you created on the first line, at the position $pos-1 indicates

If you call getAtPos($array, 3), it should return an array like this one...

```
['Charlie'=>3.3]
```

**EDIT**

You see, the $array at the top, is a key=>value array. That is, instead of having the values numbered by position, it has them tagged with a keyword.

In a normal array, e.g: [23, "Charlie", "Stackoverflow"], if you want to get the second element of the array ("Charlie"), you would have to do something like this: $var = $array[1].

In this case, as this is a key=>value array, you should look by keyword instead of position, so what you're doing there in that return is a workaround to get the keyword and value at the position you need.

What the return is doing there, is returning an array with the keyword and value for the element in the $array at the position you specify with the $pos variable.

This should be clearer than me... http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: can you please elaborate more ??

Answer (score 0):

When you apply the **array_keys()** function to $tmpArray, $keys becomes an **array** with the keys of $tmpArray as values:

`array(6) { 
[0]=> string(5) "Alpha" [1]=> string(5) "Bravo" [2]=> string(7) "Charlie" [3]=>     string(5) "Delta" [4]=> string(4) "Echo" [5]=> string(4) "Golf" 
}`

Then you are returning an **array** with the key of the position declared in $pos minus 1 (2 wich is 'Charley') and as his value the value of the position declared in $pos minus 1 of the $tmpArray **array** (2 which is 3.3).

It is confusing, you are generating a new array from some key and his value inside other array:

```
$return = array( 
        key($array[3]) => $array[3] 
);
```

Or as lascort mentioned:

`$return = getAtPos($array, 3);`